# How can I tell which files were committed for the first time at a given commit?

Tags: git

The best I have for this is to `diff` the commit's tree with its parent's, and look for additions.  E.g.

```
$ diff <( git ls-tree --name-only -r 1234567  ) \
       <( git ls-tree --name-only -r 1234567~ ) | grep '^< '
```

Is there something more civilized than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A 1234567^!
```